# Refreshing Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following Angular custom plugin to lazy load images:

https://github.com/Pentiado/angular-lazy-img

Basically, it is used like this:

```
<img lazy-img='photo.jpeg' />
```

However, when I try to do the following, the image does not consistently render:

```
<img lazy-img='{{myImageUrl}}' />
```

Doing $apply or $evalAsync doesn't work. My guess is that the directive initializes/renders before myImageUrl (which is asynchronously fetched through an API call) is resolved, evaluating it only once and then ignoring it thereafter. How should I go about resolving this?

Comment: Try wrapping it in an `<div ng-if="myImageUrl">`?

Comment: @JamesBuck that sounds promising. Giving it a try.